# Scientific articles linking personal-professional growth

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, behavior

I am writing an allegation letter to obtain funds to enroll in an activity for personal development, although the frame in which I ask for the finds is in "transversal activities related to research career". I am a PhD Student. The response to the first letter I wrote asking for funds states that the activity I requested is too related to personal growth. So I am writing the allegation to say that professional growth goes together with personal growth, that they are inseparable, for example, in creative mental estates. So, can anyone help me by pointing to scientific articles that correlate both? Or, if my supposition is wrong, articles that prove that I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between *personal development* and *professional development*, although they can cross over each other.

### Personal development

This can be achieved through

- [clinical supervision](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/15869) which is **separate and completely different to line-management but necessary for effective line-management**,
- self-awareness through self-reflection and self-evaluation,
- counselling where required

### Professional Development

This is achieved through continuing training and learning, which is recognised by your governing body as training and learning which forms part of CPD (Continuous Personal Development).

Training and learning opportunities may range from formal classes and distance learning, perhaps working towards a qualification, to informal learning experiences, such as conferences, workshops, peer discussion groups, volunteering, and so on.

Some governing bodies award "CPD Points", for example, 1 hour of CPD may count as 1 point of CPD for the year.

The following are examples of CPD (not exhaustive):

- Keeping up-to-date with current research and new books in your area of work
- Expanding your knowledge outside your area of work (only if you intend on expanding the area of your work)
- Organising further training, where relevant or to update existing skills.
  Some of this can cross over into personal development where the knowledge and learning gained helps towards this.

### Minimum CPD Required

The minimum required depends on your governing body so if you do not know, get in contact with them or you could lose your license to practice if you fail to meet the requirements.

The British Association for Counselling and Psychotherapy (BACP), for example, expects all members to gain 30 hours of CPD per year as a minimum ([BACP, n.d.](https://www.bacp.co.uk/membership/registered-membership/guide-to-cpd)) and the requirement forms [part of their ethical framework](https://www.bacp.co.uk/events-and-resources/ethics-and-standards/ethical-framework-for-the-counselling-professions/working-to-professional-standards/) everyone has to follow as a member of BACP.

### References

BACP (n.d.). *CPD Guidance for registered members* [Online]
Retreived from: https://www.bacp.co.uk/membership/registered-membership/guide-to-cpd